# Find the number of documents with filter at a particular time in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, count, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

I have documents in elasticsearch in which each document looks something like as follows:

```
{
  "id": "T12890ADSA12",
  "status": "ENDED",
  "type": "SAMPLE",
  "updatedAt": "2020-05-29T18:18:08.483Z",
  "audit": [
    {
      "event": "STARTED",
      "version": 1,
      "timestamp": "2020-04-30T13:41:25.862Z"
    },
    {
      "event": "INPROGRESS",
      "version": 2,
      "timestamp": "2020-05-14T17:03:09.137Z"
    },
    {
      "event": "INPROGRESS",
      "version": 3,
      "timestamp": "2020-05-17T17:03:09.137Z"
    },
    {
      "event": "ENDED",
      "version": 4,
      "timestamp": "2020-05-29T18:18:08.483Z"
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": "2020-04-30T13:41:25.862Z"
}
```

If I wanted to know the number of documents which are in `STARTED state` at a particular time given. How can I do that? It should use the timestamp from each event in the events field.

Edit: Mapping of the index is as follows:

```
{
  "id": "text",
  "status": "text",
  "type": "text",
  "updatedAt": "date",
  "events": [
    {
      "event": "text",
      "version": long,
      "timestamp": "date"
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": "date"
}
```

Comment: Can you share your index mapping?

Comment: @Val, I have added the mapping in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want, you need to make sure that the `events` array is of `nested` type because you have two conditions that you need to apply on each array element and this is only possible if `events` is nested:

```
    "events" : {
      "type": "nested",                     <--- you need to add this
      "properties" : {
        "event" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "version" : {
          "type" : "long"
        }
      }
    },
```

Then you'll be able to run the following `nested` query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "events",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "events.date": {
                  "gte": "2020-06-08",
                  "lte": "2020-06-08"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "events.event": "STARTED"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```